Guava CacheBuilder is blocking Rest Endpoints
When i run the code with JVM Option -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=1 my Application freezes after the first call, when i use the Guava CacheBuilder with Virtual Threads in Spring enabled.
i have the following code:
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TESTService {
    private final Cache<String, String> blockingCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();

    @SneakyThrows
    @GetMapping("sleepFromCache")
    public String sleepFromCache() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        log.info("Key is {}", uuid);
        return blockingCache.get(uuid, this::sleep);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @GetMapping("sleepDirect")
    public String sleep() {
        log.info("Sleep now!");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        log.info("Sleep ended!");
        return "TEST";
    }
}

if i then call in two seperate cmd windows these endpoints:
curl http://localhost:8080/test/sleepFromCache
and after 1 second
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
the health endpoint will not respond until the sleepFromCache is done.
if i do the same on a direct sleep endpoint
curl http://localhost:8080/test/sleepDirect
and after 1 second
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
everything is all fine and the actuator responds immediatly.
What is wrong?
